# PHP what that line means?

Tags: php, yii

I am starter php developer, I know, if else, or, elseif... but I don't understand those : ? and other symbols. So can you tell me what this lines mean:

```
$success = $success ? $b->save(false) : $success;

if (!success) // shouldn't this be without "!"
    $transaction->commit(); // this means "do the job, if ok"
  else
    $transaction->rollBack(); // this means "don't do the job, if not ok"
```

Also, can you tell me how to call this symbols, I don't know their name and so I can't find tutorials about them

Comment: Google for ternary operators in PHP.

Comment: This is a ternary operator, which is basically just a if else construct

Comment: @Irakli That is a terrible example for trying to learn about code; that is probably what threw you off. Success is true so rollback? Ugh.

Comment: @Digital Chris Yeas, I think there should be if(success) NOT if(!success)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty common in a lot of languages, you can find this **Ternary Operations** for example in javascript aswell

It is a short hand for an if/else.

The part before the `?` is the condition, the next part is the code to execute if the condition returns `true`, and the last part (after the `:`) if it returns `false`:

`condition ? if true : if false;`

`$a = 3 > 5 ? 'three is greater than five' : 'three is lesser than five';`

In this case `$a` would be `three is lesser than five`;

*I would recommend ternary operations only for very simple conditions/results, if not, you end up writting less maintainable code, sacrificing shortness for legibility*

Answer (score 2):

the above code looks like if `$success` from previous transactions was `true` , try `$b->save(false)` and then put the returned value from `$b->save(false)` into `$success`.

`$b->save(false)` means save without validation, and after successful save, will return `true`

then the `if` part is very clear

Comment: But shouldn't there be if (success) {$transaction->commit();}

Comment: that makes more sense if some other stuff went ok, do the commit, but that depends on the logic previously implemented which you havn't shown us, so I can't say

Answer (score 2):

That's a Ternary Operator, a short form for an if statement.

```
$success = $success ? $b->save(false) : $success;
```

is the same as

```
if($success) {
    $success = $b->save(false);
} else {
    $success = $success;
}
```